# WSImport fail during maven build

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, jaxws-maven-plugin

I was trying build some java project, which should be work on java1.6 and maven 3.2.3. After downloading every dependencies i got error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (importWSDL) on project CRIN_V2: Cannot execute: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin\wsimport.exe -> [Help 1]
```

Is there any reason why this plugin does not work with java1.6 and maven3.2.3? some ideas?

Comment: What happens if you try to execute `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin\wsimport.exe` from a Windows command shell?

Comment: @SteveC thanks, I'm so dumb. I have jdk1,6.0_45 installed on my disc.